# inserting new ng-click after first compile in angular js

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I'm trying to insert ng-click on a tag that will be inserted in DOM after calling a directive. I use  $compile($(this)($scope)) after appending the tag to DOM. but it doesn't work.

```
    app.directive('treeDirectiveSysAdminGuide', function ($rootScope, $compile) {
            return {
                restricts: 'A',
                replace: false,
                scope: {
                    options: '='
    }
    link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
                    var deleteNode = null;
                    scope.new_node = 'new Node';
                    scope.reload_node = function () {
                        $(element).each(function () {
                           var id = $(this).closest("li").attr("id");
                           if (treeDeleted[id] == 1)
                               $(this).addClass("deleted");
                        $(this).append("<a><i id = '" + id + "' class='fa fa-info' **ng-click='nodeInfo(" + id + ")'**></i></a>");
                        if (!$(this).find('#' + id).hasClass('compiled')) {
                            $compile($(this).find('#' + id))(scope);
                            $(this).find('#' + id).addClass('compiled');
                        }
                        $(this).before(
                            $("<a class='jstree-anchor'><i class='fa fa-circle'></i></a>")
                                .on('click', function () {
                                    scope.options.activate_node && scope.options.activate_node(id, true);
                                }));
                    });
 });
```

Comment: could you add your directive code..Also explain more what you wanted to achieve?

Comment: You shouldn't probably insert the tag to the DOM in the first place. Try to do it the angular way by using, e.g., `ng-if` or `ng-hide` to hide the element before the click

Comment: It should be like: $compile($(this))($scope);

Comment: @MajidYaghouti sorry , it didn't work for me

Comment: Where nodeInfo is declared?

Comment: @MajidYaghouti  in the controller

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
$compile($(this))($scope.$parent);
```

Additional info: Since nodeInfo() is declared in parent scope, you should pass parent scope to $compile.